Is it possible to solve overlapping objects using particle system (hair)
I'm currently working on a project where I'm using a particle system (hair) to place scattered objects within a plane. I'm facing an issue where the objects tend to overlap each other and I'm wondering if their is a way to solve this? I only find solving when using emitter.
Edit:
What I want is to have objects scattered on the plane (heart) that are randomized in size and rotation and do not hang off the edge. And that each object does not overlap each other!

The file


There's no direct way to do it, there are some tricks though, like this one (but it this case you need to make the particles real): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttJTC1AsJUI

Your solution could be Geometry nodes but you need to give more information

That sounds like a great idea!
What I want is to have objects scattered on the plane (heart) that are randomized in size and rotation and do not hang off the edge. And that each object does not overlap each other!
Thanks for helping!

Instead of of using the comment section, add all that info to your main question by using the edit button. That way, other user could give you some ideas

Thanks, I fixed that!

Here is an example of scattering cubes with Geometry Nodes.

the vertex group for the weight paint ("test") can be specified in the modifier's settings.

the values for the scaling and density (Distribute Points on Faces node) depend on the sizes of the objects. Don't forget to apply the scale to the heart and the cube (Ctrl+A).

the values for the random rotation are specified in radian values (pi=3.141...=180°).




wow! This is amazing!!
